# How come ancient Egyptian ink didn't fade during thousands of years?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

This ink's main ingredients were charcoal, honey and gum arabica.

I understand charcoal is carbon and it would remain black for long time or forever just like coal. But gum arabica is organic and I would assume it would decay just like any organic material thus breaking the carbon bond and then carbon would've just turned into dust and disappear from papyrus or clay vessels, but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: You mostly seemed to have answered your own question. I could only add that ink is a liquid so that it wicks into the nooks and crannies of the substrate (papyrus or clay). So the bond between the dry ink and the substrate is a mechanical one.

Comment: I was trying to say that ink should've disappeared by now, and we shouldn't be seeing any writings at all, but you may have answered the question, I haven't considered the fact that it bonds mechanically with media. Then I'm curious why paints once covering most Roman statues didn't survive.